# JavaFX Fontawesomefx - main app icon

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, font-awesome

I am trying to set up my main app icon using Fontawesomefx:

[image]

I'm using IntelliJ 2016 and I have imported the Maven libraries for Fontawesomefx 8.9 and Controlsfx 8.40.12 library (as it was stated it helps Fontawesomefx).

I am tying to get this very simple thing working:

[image]

I tried to cast it into Image, I tried to convert from Text to Image, I tried other types of casting and conversion yet unsuccessful so far.

Some aditional info:

```
FontAwesomeIconView extends GlyphIcon<FontAwesomeIcon> //Fontawesome lib
GlyphIcon<T extends Enum<T> & GlyphIcons> extends Text //Fontawesome lib
Text extends Shape //Java lib
Shape extends Node //Java lib
```

There are plenty links setting up an icon/text/label inside the app, but I couldn't find anything which sets the main app icon.

Any links, any help is much apreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take snapshot From node which is not on the scene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590974/how-to-take-snapshot-from-node-which-is-not-on-the-scene). (Obviously a `Node` cannot be cast to `Image` but you have to take a snapshot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a FontAwesomeIconView object as a Stage's icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198858/how-to-use-a-fontawesomeiconview-object-as-a-stages-icon)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to do this directly.

FontAwesome is a set of Unicode characters in the private use area. When you use FontAwesomeFX to create an icon what you actually get is a Text node containing a single unicode character.

The application toolbar icon is set on the Stage as a list of Image objects (you can have icons of multiple sizes). An image must be a GIF, PNG, BMP or JPEG.

You would need to convert the Text node into an Image node to achieve what you want. You could just write a one-off app to render the icon you want into a label on a panel, screenshot that, and save it into a PNG resource that you then use as your app icon.

Or you could load the icon into a node, and use the snapshot() method to create an image from the rendered representation.

Comment: This is getting way to complex to set a simple icon. My main concern is to preserve the vector functionality of the image as if converted it will loose quality. All FontAwesomeFX icons are vector based.. this is the main purpose of using this library. Else I could easily use any .png to set the icon, but it gets pixelized.

Comment: For internal icons (e.g., on an internal toolbar or menu) within your app, then FontAwesomeFX is a great way to go. For your Windows application icon you *have* to use a bitmap. But you can use a bitmap up to 256x256 pixels, so you should be able to create a high-quality version.