# JavaFX - Converting chart to image

Tags: java, image, javafx, charts, javafx-8

I have an XYChart, which displays the hours of the day on the X-axis.
I would like to save a image (or pdf) of the whole chart.
However when I display the chart, I cannot display it all, it's too big, therefore I only display a fraction (1/4 approximately).

I have found this code that allows me to do a snapshot of what is displayed in my pane :

```
@FXML
public void saveAsPng() {

    WritableImage image = chart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
    File file = new File(path);

    try {
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I can't find a way to save the whole chart as an image, without displaying it?

Has someone found a way to do so?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Reference : http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-snapshot-as-png-image/

Comment: First [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then explain what you have and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take snapshot From node which is not on the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590974/how-to-take-snapshot-from-node-which-is-not-on-the-scene)

Answer (score 1):

This will take a node

- change it's parent to be a fixed size anchor pane
- put the anchor pane inside a scroll pane
- open the scroll pane in an invisible JFrame window
- save the node as an image
- return the node back to it's previous parent.

I've used it with Charts so we can embed the images in reports, but should work with any Node.

```
void doResize(final Node node, final File file, final int aWidth, final int aHeight) {

    final AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    anchorPane.setMinSize(aWidth, aHeight);
    anchorPane.setMaxSize(aWidth, aHeight);
    anchorPane.setPrefSize(aWidth, aHeight);

    final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(anchorPane);

    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    fxPanel.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    final Pane previousParentPane = (Pane) node.getParent();

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(64, 64));
    frame.setVisible(false);
    frame.add(fxPanel);

    anchorPane.getChildren().clear();
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(node, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(node, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(node, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(node, 0.0);
    anchorPane.getChildren().add(node);

    anchorPane.layout();

    try {
        final SnapshotParameters snapshotParameters = new SnapshotParameters();
        snapshotParameters.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0.0, 0.0, aWidth, aHeight));
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(anchorPane.snapshot(snapshotParameters, new WritableImage(aWidth, aHeight)), new BufferedImage(aWidth, aHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)), "png", file);

    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Return the node back into it's previous parent
                previousParentPane.getChildren().clear();
                AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(node, 0.0);
                AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(node, 0.0);
                AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(node, 0.0);
                AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(node, 0.0);
                previousParentPane.getChildren().add(node);

                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's only one thing missing. If the node is a LineChart, and it is animated, the snapshot wont show the tick labels. The reason is, because the animation delays the appearance of the tickLabels. To avoid that issue, use chart.setAnimated(false); before taking the snapshot.